# Is it possible to put the output of one command into the middle of another

Tags: command-line, python, raspberry-pi

I am asking if there is a way to automatically put the output of a command into the middle of another.

multimon-ng outputs: `ZCZC-WXR-TOR-029037+0030-1051700-KEAX/NWS` and i want that output to get sent to where i put three question marks : `python2.7 easencode.py -z ??? output.wav`

can i do this with pipe and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
python2.7 easencode.py -z $(multimon-ng) output.wav
```

if you are in bash.

- `$( )` construct will execute command and insert result (stripped of end of line) in current command.
- as per comment, you might whish to use `"$( )"` depending of expected result and importance of space.

Comment: I'd usually quote it `"$(...)"`

Comment: it's not about "the importance of space". if `multimon-ng` fails and doesn't print anything, then `output.wav` will be passed as argument to the `-z` option, resulting in a complete cock-up.

Comment: I was thinking about a more general use of `$( )` construction.